# jQuery Find all previous element with a given data id

Tags: jquery

I would like to find all preceding elements with a give data id.

For example, if I had data-test="3" I should get data-test="2" and data-test="1":

```
 <li><a href="#" data-test="1">test</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-test="2">test</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-test="3">test</a></li>
```

I noticed prevAll function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.prevAll()` is the right approach, but you need to traverse from the `<li>`s, because the `<a>`s are not siblings of each other.

```
$('a[data-test="3"]').parent().prevAll(':has(a[data-test])').children();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NcatZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the link, and then access its parent to be able to work with `prevAll`.

```
$("a[data-test='3']").parent().prevAll().children("a")
```

After getting the previous parents, you can then get their `children` links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-test="3"]').parent().prevUntil()
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FS8tY/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can not find your preceding elements, with this markup they are in different trees of the DOM. You could change your markup like this..

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-test="1">test</a>
    <a href="#" data-test="2">test</a>
    <a href="#" data-test="3">test</a>
</li>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( $("a[data='3']").prevAll() );
    });
</script>
```

beware of the sorting, it is sorted backwards
result = [data 2, data 1]

if this would work in a tree like below, should it find `7,6,5` or `7,6,1`?
you see this command is not optimal for tree traversing in other branches of the DOM.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-test="1">test</a>
    <a href="#" data-yeah="2">test</a>
    <a href="#" data="3">test</a>
    <a href="#" data-yeah="4">test</a>
    <a href="#" data="5">test</a>
</li>
<ol id='list'>
    <li><a href="#" data-test="6">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-yeah="7">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="8">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-yeah="9">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data="10">test</a></li>
 </ol>
```

better to change the markup so, that the [`data`] is in `li` tags

```
<ol id='list'>
    <li data-test="6"><a href="#" >test</a></li>
    <li data-yeah="7"><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li data="8"><a href="#" >test</a></li>
    <li data-yeah="9"><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li data="10"><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ol>
```

so in this markup the following could find what you want

```
console.log(
    $("li[data=8]").prevAll()
);
```

this is a typically problem made by `li` tags, they are for list items, not really for major DOM structures. But anyway, perhaps someone else knows a better solution..

greetings from berlin. cheers